# Gitlab LFS support with SSH repository

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, git-lfs

I try to setup Gitlab LFS support. It's working fine for repositories cloned with HTTPS, but with SSH I always get a 404 for the LFS URLs.

The property lfs.url is set to https://gitlab-host/user/project.git/gitlab-lfs

If I debug it with pry I see that the problem is that @env['HTTP_X_SENDFILE_TYPE'].to_s is not set in function check_download_sendfile_header? in /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/lfs/response.rb

I tought it might be a problem that I am using Apache, installed the mod_xsendfile and activated it in the proxy directive, but that did not help either.

Has anyone any idea what could be the problem with LFS in a SSH cloned repo?

I'm using Gitlab version is 8.7.5 installed with omnibus.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone any idea what could be the problem with LFS in a SSH cloned repo?

[It's not yet implemented.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3589)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set the [`GITLAB_HOST`](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/tree/master#available-configuration-parameters) variable to your domain name because it will default to `localhost` and the `git lfs` push/pull will not work.